# Displaying username in header Angular6

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I've been looking for this answer everywhere. I've got a header component and I'd like to display the name of the currently logged in user.
in header.component.html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" ngbDropdownToggle>
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>USERNAME HERE<b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
```

and in header.component.ts I have this method outside of constructor and ngOnInit

```
displayName(){
    return localStorage.getItem("username");
}
```

is there a way to show that username on the header where I want it to?

Comment: in your html {{displayName()}}, see https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: @Eliseo <i class="fa fa-user"></i>{{displayName()}}<b class="caret"></b> didn't work

Comment: In function displayName put console.log("*",localStorage.getItem("username")) to see what is the value you're returned by the function

Comment: Oh I see, it returns null so displayName probably works, just gotta find the username.

Comment: In localstorage user holds all the information, id, username and email. How would I make it just show the username?

Comment: you should show what data local storage is returning

Comment: @JunKang it shows id, username and email of the currently logged in user.

Comment: You should actually show what the data looks like. Copy paste it into your question. You said `localStorage.getItem('username")` returns null right? So what is returning id, username, and email. Show us exactly what you're logging, and exactly what is being logged by copy pasting your code and log.

Comment: @JunKang oh it's an user that has id, username and email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not store the data.

How you store the userName? Where you store the data?

If you store in a item single like

```
displayName(){
   return localStorage.getItem("username"));
}
ngOnInit() {
  localStorage.setItem("username","adiós mundo");
}
```

If you store an object I supouse you have some like

```
displayName(){
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")).userName;
}
ngOnInit() {
   let data={userName:"Hola Mundo",eamil:"qqq@qqq.com"}
   localStorage.setItem("data",JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

I put the code in ngOnInit, I supouse you store the data in the submit of a form

Comment: this kinda worked. I did: `displayName(){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).username;;
     }`